# More verbose console error with Ionic 5 and Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I know this won't be a well-formed question but I struggling with this for some days.

So I have an Ionic 5 app with Angular 11.

When I do a `ionic serve` the browser runs my application nicely
but if there is an error all I see the following

[image]

I remember few versions before it listed, printed out the actual .ts file with line
where the error happened.

Is there any way to achieve this again, what I am missing?

Comment: for this could you do a global code search for `.number` ? whereever you find it put a console.log('some identifier...').

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to uninstall the local Ionic

`npm uninstall ionic`

and then install it globally

`npm uninstall -g ionic`

Looks like `ionic serve` hooked up with production(?).

I also noticed that the command was in developer mode:

`ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100`

But in production(?) mode:

`ng.cmd run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100`

I still don't get how it could be production mode as
the environment was correctly set to develop